# UIReturnKeyType MacOS Equivalent (SwiftUI)

Tags: xcode, swiftui, uikit, swift-package-manager

I am trying to partially rewrite a Swift Package Manager package for iOS so that it works in a MacOS app. I was working on turning UIKit into SwiftUI when I could not find an equivalent for this function (UIReturnKeyType).

I tried using all the known methods, like substituting the "UI" with "NS", and removing the "UI" altogether, I even searched the internet, but I found nothing. Here is the code I need to convert:

```
var keyboardReturnKeyType: UIReturnKeyType {
// some code here
}
```

Is there something that would be pretty much a drag and drop solution?